# If $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x)=-f(-x),f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$, is $f(x)+f(x+\pi)=0$ true?

Tags: functions

> If $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x)=-f(-x),f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$, is $f(x)+f(x+\pi)=0$ true?

I get $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$, and I know when $f(x)=\sin x$ it is true. but general function? is it true or a counter-example?

Comment: How did you get $f(0) = f(\pi) = 0$?  Does the line of reasoning you used apply to any function satisfying the given conditions?

Comment: @ElizabethHan let $x=0$, then $f(0)=-f(-0)=-f(0)$, so $f(0)=0$. let $x=-\pi$, then $f(\pi)=f(-\pi+2\pi)=f(-\pi)=-f(\pi)$, so $f(\pi)=0$.

Comment: Seems like you already answered your own question then!

Comment: If $f(x)$ is odd, then it can be represented as a superposition of sine functions. Using the fourier sine series of $f$, a counterexample becomes clear.

Comment: @bthmas Thank you, I get it with your cue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)+f(x+\pi)=f(x)+f(x-\pi)$$ due to the stated periodicity.

This equals $$f(x)-f(\pi-x)$$ due to the first property (odd function).

This is zero iff $$f(x)=f(\pi-x)$$

This is true in the case of $f(x)=\sin x$ due to symmetry in the line $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ but is not generally true.

A counterexample would be the function defined as $$f(x)=x, x\in(-\pi,\pi]$$ and which is periodic with period $2\pi$

Answer (score 2):

$f(\pi/2+2n\pi)=1$, $f(7\pi/2+2n\pi)=-1$, otherwise $f(x)=0$ then $f$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Are you giving a piecewise definition of a counterexample?

Comment: Thank you, I know it. thank you for your help.